# Accessing functions within embedded functions

Tags: go

First, I'm quite new to Go, so please forgive any lapses or errors in terminology. I suspect my lack of command with the terminology is also partially to blame for not finding an answer to the following question after many hours of looking.

In short, I would like the output of the following code to be

```
I am the Adult
I am the Child
```

Where instead the output is

```
I am the Adult
I am the Adult
```

Code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Human struct {
    age  uint
    name string
}

func (h Human) sayName() error {
    fmt.Println("I am the Adult")
    return nil
}

func (h Human) Introduce() error {
    h.sayName()
    return nil
}

type Child struct {
    Human
}

func (c Child) sayName() error {
    fmt.Println("I am the Child")
    return nil
}

func main() {
    h := Human{}
    h.Introduce()

    c := Child{Human{}}
    c.Introduce()
}
```

So in essence, though Introduce() is only implemented in the embedded type, Human, it calls sayName(), which is implemented in both the embedded type and the embedding type.

I understand that the current output is the way as it is because the embedded Human struct doesn't "know" it's embedded and thus could never call Child.sayName and would only call its own sayName() function.

Is there a way to instantiate a Human struct (or a struct embedding one) in which you can "replace" Human.sayName() with an alternate sayName() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get this kind of late-bound behavior is to use interfaces. If `Introduce` was a method on an interface that required a `sayName` method, then `Human` and `Child`  would both satisfy that interface, and could `Introduce` themselves, and the proper `sayName` method would be called in either case, because it would be dispatched via the interface type, instead of via `Human`.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Instead of Introduce() being a function that is received by any particular struct, it changes to a function that has no defined receiver, but instead takes **as an argument** a "Talker" interface where Talker is defined as a struct implementing sayName()?

Comment: @user306537 yes. Sadly go doesn't allow defining methods with interface recievers (which would allow interfaces to function as roles).

Answer (score 0):

What you would like to do is not possible. As you stated, the `Human` type could never know that it's embedded in the `Child` type and therefor when `Introduce` is called it has no way of invoking the `Child` types version of `sayName()`. You're trying to invert the relationship, to have an embedded type call out to another version of it's method in the embeddor.

Methods for an embedded type are hoisted to the scope of the embeddor but that is a one way street, which is sensible. In this situation you would just need to structure your code differently. Most likely, whatever behavior you're looking for can be achieved with the use of interfaces rather than embedding. I would provide more of an example but with your code sample there isn't much to say, obviously to solve the problem here you would just call `sayName()` and would never define `Introduce` in the first place since it does nothing.

It's possible you should just be embedding in the opposite direction. `Human` contains no reference to `Child` but `Child` does have a reference to `Human` and, in a case like this, where both have a definition for `sayName()`, `Child` could call `Human`'s by doing `c.Human.sayName()`. So my intuition says you've embedded in the wrong direction or you should use interfaces. This is purely an assumption, but I would guess you might have the wrong idea since you're referring to `Human` as the and 'adult' (like the parent) and `Child` as child (like a child class). This isn't the case at all. Embedding is the same as composition only the embedded types methods and fields are hoisted or lifted or whatever term you like to say they're moved up to the scope of the embeddor. That being said, I see a lot of confusion around this on SO and it's almost always because the asker is looking at this like it's inheritance when really it's composition.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer; I feared as much. The actual application I intended this behavior for was for testing Go bindings for a C library for hardware management. I have cgo calls in functions, and when those functions are being tested, I wanted to create a "testdevice" embedding the original "device" type, where I replaced the cgo function-calling functions with functions for the "testdevice" with test functions that just returned C structures from a table. I suspect I need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @user306537 as hobbs also points out below, the way to do this is with an interface. Rather than using embedding, make it so those functions are called from an interface. Then in the test code you have your own implementation of the interface which you use in place of the real one. This is in my experience by far the most common way to achieve things like this in test. You also see similar design quite a bit in the std lib, with things like httproundtripper.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about it incorrectly. as hobbs and evanmcdonnal said, the "correct" way to do this is to make the Introduce() function a function with an interface argument and then to create an interface which both Child and Human implement.

The following gives the desired output:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Talker interface {
    sayName() error
}

type Human struct {
    age  uint
    name string
}

func (h Human) sayName() error {
    fmt.Println("I am the Adult")
    return nil
}

type Child struct {
    Human
}

func Introduce(t Talker) error {
    t.sayName()
    return nil
}

func (c Child) sayName() error {
    fmt.Println("I am the Child")
    return nil
}

func main() {
    h := Human{}
    Introduce(h)

    c := Child{Human{}}
    Introduce(c)
}
```